# Displaying a calendar in ADF Mobile application

Tags: listview, mobile, oracle-adf

I need to display a calendar that is stored in Oracle database in ADF Mobile application. Please advise me how to achieve this.

Added later :

I have a calendar that is stored in oracle database. The calendar has the following details. 1) Holidays 2) tasks to be performed on each working day. I am planning to display the calendar in a 5x7 table. I developed a web service to retrieve all the data. But, I am having difficulties mapping this data to elements in amx page. any pointers as to how to achieve this can be very helpful

Comment: This is extremely vague. Can you expand on this?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a calendar that is stored in oracle database. The calendar has the following details. 1) Holidays 2) tasks to be performed on each working day. I am planning to display the calendar in a 5x7 table. I developed a web service to retrieve all the data. But, I am having difficulties mapping this data to elements in amx page. any pointers as to how to achieve this can be very helpful.

Comment: Describe this in your question, thanks.

Comment: Added. Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used amx:iterator inside a table layout. I will post the sample code i used later.

Answer (score 0):

Map the data that comes from your WS to a POJO datacontrol which you can than use to consume in your .amx page
This can be useful as well:
https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2613349

Comment: The link you posted is the same question I posted in Oracle forums. I was able to display a table using an iterator.